# jquery issue with jquery ui accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have an accordion on my website and I use the jquery UI accordion function for it.  It was working fine before when my code looked this like:

```
$ (function () {
   $( "#accordion" ) .accordion({
      collapsible: true
   });
});
```

And now I added some code to add more function and the accordion stopped working.  This is what it looks like now:

```
$ (function () {
   $( "#accordion" ) .accordion({
      collapsible: true,
      change: function(event, ui) {
         if(ui.newHeader[0].id == "cars") {
            $("#homesearch").val('');
         } else {
            $("#carsearch").val('');
         }
      }
   });
});
```

Any suggestions on what I have done wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma after `collapsible: true` / before `change:`

Comment: good eye, however, I added that ; and it still isnt working.  Thanks for a great answer though.

Comment: @Rookieatthis do you get an error in the console by any chance?

Comment: @Rookieatthis so when you remove the `change` event it works again?  Update the `change` to be much simpler (e.g. do nothing).

Comment: @Rookieatthis after checking .. doesn't look like `change` is an `accordion` option.  I think you want to bind an `'accordionchange'` event to the object (as simple as `$("#accordion").accordion(...).bind('accordionchange', function ...)`